Insert a model element field such as requirement name to content inside the requirement's link document
I have a requirement and the content of the requirement is inside a linked document, not the notes sections.
I wish to add some of the element details, such as the requirement name to the text inside the linked document.
Is this possible and if so, any explanation of how to do it?

You can access the document, but it's rather tricky. Will see if I can gather the details...

How do you want to add these details? In code? Do you have existing code already? What did you try? Please clarifly and add the information to your question.
